# Need help deleting rows/lines in richtextbox c# win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

So essentially, I have a button, when I press the button, the button should delete the most recent row of text embedded into the rich text box. Press it again, it should delete the next line above that etc.

I tried a using .substring, which it worked, but required me to double click the button instead of a single click..

Furthermore, when I press the add text button it should replace the deleted line. Currently, the delete button *button1_click* just removes all lines, but all I want the it to do is remove a line of text from the richtextbox.

Edit:
Huge apologies before, I forgot to add the code as mentioned in replies, apologies.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] texts = new string[10];
    int i = 0;
    
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox.Text == "")
        {
            texts[i] = texts[i];
        }
        else
        {
            texts[i] += TextBox.Text + "\r\n";
            richText.Text += texts[i];
            ++i;
            TextBox.Text = "";
        }
        
        
    }

    private void richText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //i dont know need to do research or im too dumb 
        richText.Text = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++)
        {
            texts[i] = "";
        }

        i = 0;

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587505/delete-the-last-line-of-rich-text-box

        //works, but double click instead of one click

    }
}
```

}

To clarify, the left button adds text from the textbox and the right button is basically the function aforementioned.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fASdb.png)

Thanks to anyone who helps!

Comment: The [`RichTextBox.Lines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines) property should help with this.

Comment: Which is *the most recent row of text*? The last one? Any line last inserted anywhere?

Comment: The last line that was inserted basically. if that helps simplifies things.

Comment: Inserted *where*? Anywhere (any position)? Are you keeping track of this? Is the user inserting lines or your code is? -- Try to be as specific as possible. If you have any code you wrote for this, post that, too.

Comment: This all sounds odd to me…. You state that you want… _”when I press the add text button it should replace the deleted line.”_ … ? … This is odd in a sense that nothing is going to keep track of the “deleted” lines. If you want a newly added line to “replace” the LAST deleted line… then YOUR code is going to have to keep track of what lines were deleted AND where they were in the text box when deleted.

Comment: In addition, if you are wanting to … _”I have a button, when I press the button, the button should delete the most recent row of text embedded into the rich text box.”_ … ? … I sympathize with your users since the deleted line may not necessarily be the “selected” line. Again, nothing is going to keep track of the “most recently” added lines and YOUR code will have to keep track of the added lines and where they were added.

Comment: I am just saying that what you describe seems neither user friendly and certainly is going to require you to write a bunch of code to juggle the added and deleted lines not to mention other problems. I am guessing that a `DataTable`’s `GetChanges` property “may” help, but it will still require some extra code to manage what you describe.

Comment: Oh this isn't me shipping out products, i'm just brushing over a subject regarding Array's. You are right this isn't user friendly, but it was never intended to be. 

Basically the last line of text is to be deleted and if pressed again it should continue deleting the last line within the rows of text. I can clear an entire richtextbox but i can't clear each individual line of text. 

Sorry if I didn't explain the problem well enough

Comment: Well… a `TextBox` does not have a “delete line at line X index” method. If you wanted to delete the LAST line in the text box you could do something like… `TextBox.Lines = TextBox.Lines.Take(TextBox.Lines.Length - 1).ToArray();` … to delete the FIRST line in the text box you could do something like…  `TextBox.Lines = TextBox.Lines.Skip(1).ToArray();` … obviously you could Skip more lines or Take more lines.

Comment: However, if you wanted to delete lines out of the middle of the text, then you will have to re-build the entire text of lines by possibly using a combination of Skip and Take or some other strategy. Bottom line… your code will have to re-build the entire set of lines in the text if you want to add and delete lines as you describe.